# How to correctly write a command/macro which returns a dimension

Tags: macros, dimension-expressions

I am trying to write a command/macro which would return a dimension that can be used to configure an environment I've created.

For example I have a `TwoColumn` environment where I want to include a vertical offset of 4.5pt:

```
\begin{TwoColumns}{4.5pt}{chant}
    ... Content ...
\end{TwoColumns}
```

Instead of a maintaining a list of fixed dimensions, there are only a few parameters needed to generate the exact vertical spacing. I wrote a command which takes parameters to compute the dimension of interest. Calling the following command *by itself* does compute the 4.5pt dimension correctly according to the console output:

```
\GetTopMarginAdjust{la}{c3}{sameLine}
```

However, when using this new command as an argument to `\vspace`, it throws an error: *Missing number, treated as zero*. Similarly with my `TwoColumn` environment.

```
\vspace{\GetTopMarginAdjust{la}{c3}{sameLine}}
```

What am I missing? How might I do this in the right way, or better way?

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{xifthen}

% Heading to top staff line c3/f3 clef
%    No divisio minima, no Mi note, no descenders in ChantBoxCentered
\newdimen\vspaceAbsCThreeCB
\vspaceAbsCThreeCB=10.5pt

% Heading to top staff line c4 clef
%    No divisio minima, no descenders in ChantBoxCentered
\newdimen\vspaceAbsCFourCB
\vspaceAbsCFourCB=4pt

% Delta between ChantBoxCentered (English) and TwoColumn (Latin) environments
\newdimen\vspaceDeltaEnv
\vspaceDeltaEnv=6pt

% Delta between twoLine and sameLine (absolute difference)
\newdimen\vspaceDeltaLineOption
\vspaceDeltaLineOption=0.5pt

\newcommand{\tempValueLanguageAndClef}{0pt}
\newcommand{\tempValueLineOption}{0pt}

%
% GetTopMarginAdjust
%    Argument #1: (str) language (la or en)
%    Argument #2: (str) clef (c3 or c4)
%    Argument #3: (str) lineOption (sameLine or twoLine)
%
\newcommand{\GetTopMarginAdjust}[3]{
    % Set basic environment: Get the language and clef
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{en}}{%
        % ChantBoxCentered (English)
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{c3}}{%
            % c3 clef
            \renewcommand{\tempValueLanguageAndClef}{\vspaceAbsCThreeCB}
        }{%
            % c4 clef
            \renewcommand{\tempValueLanguageAndClef}{\vspaceAbsCFourCB}
        }
    }{%
        % TwoColumn (Latin)
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{c3}}{%
            % c3 clef
            \renewcommand{\tempValueLanguageAndClef}{\dimexpr \vspaceAbsCThreeCB-\vspaceDeltaEnv\relax}
        }{%
            % c4 clef
            \renewcommand{\tempValueLanguageAndClef}{\dimexpr \vspaceAbsCFourCB-\vspaceDeltaEnv\relax}
        }
    }%
    
    % Set delta needed for the line option
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{sameLine}}{%
        \renewcommand{\tempValueLineOption}{0pt}
    }{%
        \renewcommand{\tempValueLineOption}{\vspaceDeltaLineOption}
    }
    
    \typeout{dim: \the\dimexpr \tempValueLanguageAndClef+\tempValueLineOption\relax; Options: #1, #2, #3}
    \the\dimexpr \tempValueLanguageAndClef+\tempValueLineOption\relax
}

\begin{document}

\GetTopMarginAdjust{en}{c3}{sameLine}
\GetTopMarginAdjust{la}{c3}{sameLine}

% Doesn't work
\vspace{\GetTopMarginAdjust{la}{c3}{sameLine}}

% Doesn't work
\newdimen\tempOffset
\tempOffset=\GetTopMarginAdjust{la}{c3}{sameLine}

\typeout{\tempOffset}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that for the way you want to use your `\GetTopMarginAdjust` it has to be fully expandable, but the conditionals defined with `xifthen` and your assignments you do for the calculation aren't fully expandable.

The following uses `\str_case:nnF` of `expl3` instead to get some fully expandable string-based branching.

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{book}

% Heading to top staff line c3/f3 clef
%    No divisio minima, no Mi note, no descenders in ChantBoxCentered
\newdimen\vspaceAbsCThreeCB
\vspaceAbsCThreeCB=10.5pt

% Heading to top staff line c4 clef
%    No divisio minima, no descenders in ChantBoxCentered
\newdimen\vspaceAbsCFourCB
\vspaceAbsCFourCB=4pt

% Delta between ChantBoxCentered (English) and TwoColumn (Latin) environments
\newdimen\vspaceDeltaEnv
\vspaceDeltaEnv=6pt

% Delta between twoLine and sameLine (absolute difference)
\newdimen\vspaceDeltaLineOption
\vspaceDeltaLineOption=0.5pt

\ExplSyntaxOn
\msg_new:nnn { fong } { unknown-language } { Unknown~ language~ `#1'. }
\msg_new:nnn { fong } { unknown-clef } { Unknown~ clef~ `#1'. }
\msg_new:nnn { fong } { unknown-lineoption } { Unknown~ lineoption~ `#1'. }
\cs_new:Npn \fong_topmargin_adjust:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \dim_eval:n
      {
        \str_case:nnF {#2}
          {
            { c3 } { \vspaceAbsCThreeCB }
            { c4 } { \vspaceAbsCFourCB }
          }
          {
            \msg_expandable_error:nnn { fong } { unknown-clef } {#2}
            \vspaceAbsCThreeCB % fallback value
          }
        \str_case:nnF {#1}
          {
            { en } { }
            { la } { - \vspaceDeltaEnv }
          }
          { \msg_expandable_error:nnn { fong } { unknown-language } {#1} }
        \str_case:nnF {#3}
          {
            { sameLine } { }
            { twoLine  } { + \vspaceDeltaLineOption }
          }
          { \msg_expandable_error:nnn { fong } { unknown-lineoption } {#3} }
      }
  }
\cs_new_eq:NN \GetTopMarginAdjust \fong_topmargin_adjust:nnn
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\GetTopMarginAdjust{en}{c3}{sameLine}
\GetTopMarginAdjust{la}{c3}{sameLine}

% Works
\vspace{\GetTopMarginAdjust{la}{c3}{sameLine}}

% Works
\newdimen\tempOffset
\tempOffset=\GetTopMarginAdjust{la}{c3}{sameLine}

\typeout{\the\tempOffset}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, Skillmon. Though the syntax appears foreign, I like the case option. Time to do some reading.

Comment: @MatthewFong yes, on first look `expl3` looks strange from a TeX-accustomed point of view, but it adds a lot of structure, so once you got the basics it's relatively easy to understand, certainly a lot easier than my own non-`expl3` code :)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to TeX.SE. `\vpsace` requires something that *expands* to a ⟨glue⟩, however your `\GetTopMarginAdjust` macro is not expandable.

One way out of this is to make this macro store its result in a dimen or skip register (the latter being that used by LaTeX's `\newlength`; contrary to dimen registers, skip registers have shrink and stretch components); then the register can be used inside the argument of `\vspace`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xifthen}

% Heading to top staff line c3/f3 clef
%    No divisio minima, no Mi note, no descenders in ChantBoxCentered
\newcommand{\vspaceAbsCThreeCB}{10.5pt}

% Heading to top staff line c4 clef
%    No divisio minima, no descenders in ChantBoxCentered
\newcommand{\vspaceAbsCFourCB}{4pt}

% Delta between ChantBoxCentered (English) and TwoColumn (Latin) environments
\newcommand{\vspaceDeltaEnv}{6pt}

% Delta between twoLine and sameLine (absolute difference)
\newcommand{\vspaceDeltaLineOption}{0.5pt}

\newcommand{\tempValueLanguageAndClef}{}
\newcommand{\tempValueLineOption}{}

\newdimen\topMarginAdjustResult % where \topMarginAdjust stores its result

% \topMarginAdjust
%    Argument #1: (str) language (la or en)
%    Argument #2: (str) clef (c3 or c4)
%    Argument #3: (str) lineOption (sameLine or twoLine)
%
\newcommand*{\topMarginAdjust}[3]{%
    % Set basic environment: Get the language and clef
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{en}}{%
        % ChantBoxCentered (English)
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{c3}}{%
            % c3 clef
            \let\tempValueLanguageAndClef\vspaceAbsCThreeCB
        }{%
            % c4 clef
            \let\tempValueLanguageAndClef\vspaceAbsCFourCB
        }%
    }{%
        % TwoColumn (Latin)
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{c3}}{%
            % c3 clef
            \edef\tempValueLanguageAndClef{%
                \the\dimexpr \vspaceAbsCThreeCB-\vspaceDeltaEnv\relax}%
        }{%
            % c4 clef
            \edef\tempValueLanguageAndClef{%
              \the\dimexpr \vspaceAbsCFourCB-\vspaceDeltaEnv\relax}%
        }%
    }%
    %
    % Set delta needed for the line option
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{sameLine}}{%
        \renewcommand{\tempValueLineOption}{0pt}%
    }{%
        \edef\tempValueLineOption{\vspaceDeltaLineOption}
    }%
    % This because \topMarginAdjustResult is a dimen register; if it were a
    % macro, you would use \edef and \the\dimexpr ... \relax inside.
    \topMarginAdjustResult=%
      \dimexpr \tempValueLanguageAndClef+\tempValueLineOption\relax
}

\begin{document}

Foo\par
\topMarginAdjust{la}{c3}{sameLine}%
\vspace{\topMarginAdjustResult}

Bar\par
\topMarginAdjust{en}{c3}{sameLine}%
\vspace{\topMarginAdjustResult}

Baz

\newdimen\tempOffset
\topMarginAdjust{la}{c3}{sameLine}%
\tempOffset=\topMarginAdjustResult

\typeout{\the\tempOffset} % 4.5pt

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another way is to store the result in a macro: you can have a single macro that is reused every time, or alternatively add a parameter to `\topMarginAdjust` that specifies the macro name used for storing the result of the computation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xifthen}

% Heading to top staff line c3/f3 clef
%    No divisio minima, no Mi note, no descenders in ChantBoxCentered
\newcommand{\vspaceAbsCThreeCB}{10.5pt}

% Heading to top staff line c4 clef
%    No divisio minima, no descenders in ChantBoxCentered
\newcommand{\vspaceAbsCFourCB}{4pt}

% Delta between ChantBoxCentered (English) and TwoColumn (Latin) environments
\newcommand{\vspaceDeltaEnv}{6pt}

% Delta between twoLine and sameLine (absolute difference)
\newcommand{\vspaceDeltaLineOption}{0.5pt}

\newcommand{\tempValueLanguageAndClef}{}
\newcommand{\tempValueLineOption}{}

\newcommand{\topMarginAdjustResult}{}% where \topMarginAdjust stores its result

% \topMarginAdjust
%    Argument #1: (str) language (la or en)
%    Argument #2: (str) clef (c3 or c4)
%    Argument #3: (str) lineOption (sameLine or twoLine)
%
\newcommand*{\topMarginAdjust}[3]{%
    % Set basic environment: Get the language and clef
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{en}}{%
        % ChantBoxCentered (English)
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{c3}}{%
            % c3 clef
            \let\tempValueLanguageAndClef\vspaceAbsCThreeCB
        }{%
            % c4 clef
            \let\tempValueLanguageAndClef\vspaceAbsCFourCB
        }%
    }{%
        % TwoColumn (Latin)
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{c3}}{%
            % c3 clef
            \edef\tempValueLanguageAndClef{%
                \the\dimexpr \vspaceAbsCThreeCB-\vspaceDeltaEnv\relax}%
        }{%
            % c4 clef
            \edef\tempValueLanguageAndClef{%
              \the\dimexpr \vspaceAbsCFourCB-\vspaceDeltaEnv\relax}%
        }%
    }%
    %
    % Set delta needed for the line option
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{sameLine}}{%
        \renewcommand{\tempValueLineOption}{0pt}%
    }{%
        \edef\tempValueLineOption{\vspaceDeltaLineOption}
    }%
    %
    \edef\topMarginAdjustResult{%
      \the\dimexpr \tempValueLanguageAndClef+\tempValueLineOption\relax
    }%
}

\begin{document}

Foo\par
\topMarginAdjust{la}{c3}{sameLine}%
\vspace{\topMarginAdjustResult}

Bar\par
\topMarginAdjust{en}{c3}{sameLine}%
\vspace{\topMarginAdjustResult}

Baz

% TeX way:
\newdimen\tempOffset
\topMarginAdjust{la}{c3}{sameLine}%
\tempOffset=\topMarginAdjustResult\relax % don't remove the \relax

% LaTeX way:
% \newlength{\tempOffset}%
% \topMarginAdjust{la}{c3}{sameLine}%
% \setlength{\tempOffset}{\topMarginAdjustResult}%

\typeout{\the\tempOffset} % 4.5pt

\end{document}
```

Same output as above.

Comment: Thank you, frougon. Definitely a solution that I can understand at first glance.